# How to redirect the IF Else output to html file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written code to get hypertreding status of Windows servers. I am not able to redirect the output to html file. Could you please help here:

```
$vCores = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure -Property  NumberOfCores -Sum
$vCores = $vCores.Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure -Property  NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = $vLogicalCPUs.sum
    if ($vLogicalCPUs -gt $vCores) { 
       “Hyperthreading: Enabled”
    } 
   else {  “Hyperthreading: Disabled”
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next *commented* code snippet could help

```
$vCores = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure -Property  NumberOfCores -Sum
$vCores = $vCores.Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | 
                Measure -Property  NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = $vLogicalCPUs.sum

    if ($vLogicalCPUs -gt $vCores) { 
       $aux = 'Hyperthreading: Enabled'
    } 
    else {
       $aux = 'Hyperthreading: Disabled'
    }

'' # linebreak for better readibility
$aux | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header "attribute","attrValue" |
       ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment

'<BR>' # linebreak in HTML for better readibility
$aux.Split(": ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) |
       ConvertFrom-Csv |
       ConvertTo-Html -Property Hyperthreading -As List -Fragment
```

**Output**:

```
<table>
<tr><td>attribute:</td><td>Hyperthreading</td></tr>
<tr><td>attrValue:</td><td>Disabled</td></tr>
</table>
<BR>
<table>
<tr><td>Hyperthreading:</td><td>Disabled</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Output rendered:**

attribute:Hyperthreading
attrValue:Disabled

Hyperthreading:Disabled

Answer (score 0):

First I create an empty array called `$HyperThreading`. Then created a custom property value using `New-Object`. Using the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add the header. From here we convert it into HTML and send it to a file.

```
$vCores = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure -Property  NumberOfCores -Sum
$vCores = $vCores.Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure -Property  NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum
$vLogicalCPUs = $vLogicalCPUs.sum
$HyperThreading = @()
    if ($vLogicalCPUs -gt $vCores) { 
       $HT=“Hyper Threading: Enabled”
    } 
   else {  $HT=“Hyper Threading: Disabled”
    }
    $HThreading = New-Object psobject
    $HThreading | Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -Name "Hyper_Threading" -Value "$HT" -Force
    $HyperThreading += $HThreading
    $HyperThreading | ConvertTo-Html -title "Hyper Threading" -body "<H2>Hyper Threading Information.</H2>" | 
    Set-Content F:\Test\Hyper_Threading.html
```

If you have issues let me know.